# GlobalExceptionHandler does not marshall to JSON when mapping produces application/vnd.ms-powerpoint

Tags: java, json, spring

I have method in a Spring Controller class that returns FileSystemResources and produces application/vnd.ms-powerpoint. In case of success I managed to get the ppt file properly. However the problem starts when this method throws an exception. I have set a GlobalExceptionHandler which render JSON error message and it works fine for all the 50 methods that I have that produce application/json but this one that produces application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.

I have done a lot of research in this area, using ResponseEntity<> instead, write the content directly in the response, set the response header in the GlobalExceptionHandler and it only works if I return a simple String and the response seemingly to be text/html and I don't the json that I am expecting.

Method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/presentation/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation")
@ResponseBody
public FileSystemResource toPPTX(@PathVariable String id, HttpServletResponse response) throws DiagramExporterException {
     response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation");
     response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=result.pptx");
     return new FileSystemResource(presentationService.exportToPPTX());
}
```

Method in the GlobalExceptionHandler:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
@ExceptionHandler(DiagramExporterException.class)
@ResponseBody
ErrorInfo handleDiagramExporterException(HttpServletRequest request, DiagramExporterException e) {
    logger.warn("DiagramExporterException: " + request.getRequestURL(), e.getMessage());
    return new ErrorInfo(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, request.getRequestURL(), e.getMessage());
}
```

The GlobalException should marshall the ErrorInfo object and it works for all the cases but the ppt. If I add a break point in the ExceptionHandler method it stops there, but the output isn't right

Here is the header in case of an error

```
{
  "date": "Sun, 18 Dec 2016 18:26:05 GMT",
  "server": "Apache-Coyote/1.1",
  "connection": "close",
  "content-length": "4897",
  "content-language": "en",
  "content-type": "text/html;charset=utf-8"
}
```

I tried many suggestions proposed here and could not solve the problem. I should return ErrorInfo and not a String, many other layers are unmarshalling to ErrorInfo

**SOLUTION**

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
@ExceptionHandler(NotFoundTextPlainException.class)
@ResponseBody
ResponseEntity<String> handleNotFoundTextPlainException(HttpServletRequest request, NotFoundTextPlainException e) {
// serialise to JSON !
return toJsonResponse(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, request, e.getMessage());
}
```

Any ideas, please ?
Thank you very much.

Comment: did you try to write in the `@RequestMapping` this **`produces = {"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation","application/json"})`** so you tell spring that the method can return or a ppt or a json

Comment: @AngeloImmediata I have tried before and just in case I tried it again. I still get the error instead of the json. 
that's the curl command curl -X GET --header 'Accept: text/html' 'http://localhost:8585/exporter/presentation/100
for other methods I have basically the same annotations and the cUrl call looks like curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: text/plain' --header 'Accept: application/json'. Looks like the FileSystemResource change the header somehow. I have no idea. Thanks for your suggestion